# Ansible: How to get files that newly created by shell script?

Tags: python, ansible

I am creating an Ansible playbook which builds some code and copies result to my server. Like this:

```
- name: build web packages
  local_action:
    script build.sh
    chdir: {{ item.path }}/build.sh
  with_items: {{ packages }}

- name: upload static files
  synchronize:
    # This should be a loop
    src: {{ item.path }}/built_files  # How to get output files
    dest: {{ deploy_dir }}/{{ item.name }}
```

Besides built files, there are also some other files in build directory, which I do not want to copy.

Different packages may build into different folders, so maybe I need to monitor my local directory and diff files? How could I do it?

Comment: I'm struggling writing loops... Maybe I will answer this question myself if I succeeded. Now I found "Include" directive suits well in my case.

Comment: You have just removed a vital comment in which you specified that you **do not want** to copy files existing before build. Can you decide what your objective is?

Comment: Ok I thought we delete comments to make comments clear. I didn't find similar question here, so I want to share it with who need it. I'm sorry for being misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too complex to write code for you, so a conceptual answer:

1. Use [`find` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/find_module.html) locally on `path` in a loop over `packages`.
2. Flatten the results to get a list of paths to existing files in a variable named `files_before`.
3. Use `build web packages` task as posted in your question.
4. Use `find` module locally on `path` in a loop over `packages` (same as the first task).
5. Flatten the results to get a list of paths to existing files in a variable named `files_after`.
6. Use [`copy` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/copy_module.html) (not `synchronize`) in a loop over a [difference](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters) between  `files_after` and `files_before`.

You can implement flattening either in separate `set_fact` tasks, or directly in the `with_items` declaration in the last task.

You might also have to use [path filters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#id7) and string manipulation to convert paths to relative ones to specify destination directories.

---

Now, if your build process creates also subdirectories and you want to retain the structure, add tasks equivalent to the above ones, but limit `find` scope to directories and use [`file` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/file_module.html) to create them on targets machines.

---

If you think that the above looks complicated, it is, but bear in mind that you specified the requirement and the tool.

On top of that, the whole play would be able to run only once (unless you deleted and recreated the local repository earlier in the play).

Answer (score 1):

I also came up with an idea using timestamp.

```
# main.yaml
- name: build and upload packages
  include: web.yaml     # Use include_tasks if version >= 2.4
  with_items:
    - name: package1
      path: path1       # build directory
    - name: package2
      path: path2
    ...
  loop_control:
    loop_var: package

# web.yaml
- name: record begin timestamp
  local_action: command date +%s
  register: build_begin_ts

- name: build packages
  local_action:
    module: command bash build.sh       # Use script module if version >= 2.4
    chdir: "{{ package.path }}"

- name: record done timestamp
  local_action: command date +%s
  register: build_done_ts

- name: find built files
  local_action:
    module: find
    paths: "{{ package.path }}"
    file_type: any
    recurse: yes
    age: "{{ (build_begin_ts.stdout | int) - (build_done_ts.stdout | int) }}s"
  register: built_files

- name: upload built files
  copy:
    src: "{{ item.path }}"
    dest: "{{ target_path }}/{{ item.path | basename }}"
  with_items: "{{ built_files.files }}"
```